# How to debug "cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory"?

Tags: linker, shared-libraries

On our project at work, where I use a build system managed by another team, I am running into an issue where I am able to compile and link the binary, but then when executing it, it complains about being unable to load a shared object file, it should never have been linked against:

```
/home/me/build/bin/executable: error while loading shared libraries: libicui18n.so.52.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

The curious part is, that the only instance of the file name `libicui18n.so.52.1` I can even find on my machine are `/opt/onlyoffice/desktopeditors/libicui18n.so.52.1` and `/home/me/.local/opt/foxitsoftware/foxitreader/lib/libicui18n.so.52.1`, which I definitely *don't* link against, at least according to linker command executed by the build system:

- It does not occur as any of the explicit `/absolute/path/to/libsomething.so.42.3` files.
- Nothing related is given as `-L` option.
- Nothing related is given as `/absolute/path/to/libsomething.a` file.
- Nothing related is in `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` or `$LIBRARY_PATH`.
- The Intel Fortran compiler has no reason to include those in the default paths.

So now I am wondering, how else the `libicui18n.so.52.1` may be linked against, and how I may go about debugging such an issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> how else the libicui18n.so.52.1 may be linked against

ELF libraries can specify "what name should be used at runtime" *independently* of the name of the library itself. Example:

```
gcc -fPIC -shared -o libt.so t.c -Wl,--soname=libfoo.so.1.2.3
gcc main.c -L. -lt

./a.out
./a.out: error while loading shared libraries: libfoo.so.1.2.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Here, the library is built in a way which requires `libfoo.so.1.2.3` at runtime, although no such library exists. It is up to the packaging system to provide such library (or a symlink).

You can examine a library to see what name it expects to be used at runtime like so:

```
readelf -d libt.so | grep SONAME
 0x000000000000000e (SONAME)             Library soname: [libfoo.so.1.2.3]
```

You can examine the list of libraries `a.out` requires at runtime like so:

```
 readelf -d ./a.out | grep NEEDED
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libfoo.so.1.2.3]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libc.so.6]
```

> how I may go about debugging such an issue.

As above. Your next question is probably "how can I *fix* this issue?".

Since `libicui18n.so.52.1` *is* installed, but not installed into a directory which the dynamic linker will search by default, all you have to do is tell your binary to add the non-standard `/opt/onlyoffice/desktopeditors` directory the list of directories to search.

You do that by adding `-Wl,-rpath=/opt/onlyoffice/desktopeditors` to your executable's link line.

You can also add `/opt/onlyoffice/desktopeditors` to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, but using `-Wl,-rpath` is preferred.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply; It helped me ensure that my hotfix (symlink) is doing the right thing, and not creating some brittle situation, and improve the overall robustness.